# Suitescript 2.x: Create a Customer Deposit upon Approval of Sales Order

Tags: suitescript, suitescript2.0

Can you please check my code. I want to create a Customer Deposit upon approval of Sales Order. However, the Customer Deposit is both being created in Pending Approval and Pending Fulfillment. Can you please help fix my code. Thank you!

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType UserEventScript
 */
 define(["N/record"], function (record) {
    try {
        function afterSubmit(scriptContext) {

            if (scriptContext.type == scriptContext.UserEventType.CREATE || scriptContext.type == scriptContext.UserEventType.EDIT) {

                var objSoRecord = scriptContext.newRecord;
                log.debug("Load the Sales Order", objSoRecord);

                var intsoId = objSoRecord.id;
                log.debug("Get the Sales Order Id: " , intsoId)
              
                var stCustomer = objSoRecord.getValue({
                    fieldId: 'entity'
                });
                log.debug("Customer ", stCustomer)

                //Get Values

              var checkStatus = objSoRecord.getValue('status');
                log.debug("SO status: " , checkStatus);

                if (checkStatus !== "Pending Approval"|| checkStatus == "Pending Fulfillment") {

                    var objcustDeposit = record.create({
                        type: record.Type.CUSTOMER_DEPOSIT,
                        isDynamic: true,
                    defaultValues: {
                        'entity': stCustomer,
                        'salesorder': intsoId
                        }

                    });
                    
//Insert Code here

                    var saveCustDep = objcustDeposit.save();

                }
                         
            }
        }

    } catch (error) {
        log.debug("Capture Error:", error);
    }

    return {
       afterSubmit: afterSubmit
    }
});
```

N/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/A

Answer (score 0):

Your `checkStatus` condition

```
if (checkStatus !== "Pending Approval"|| checkStatus == "Pending Fulfillment") {
```

essentially breaks down to "if `checkStatus` is anything except `Pending Approval`, create the Deposit". You'll need to fix the condition.

I might suggest you compare the old value of the status field and the new value of the status field, and only create the Deposit when the status *changes* to `Pending Approval`. If you only look at the current status, then any edits while in the `Pending Approval` status will trigger further Deposit creations.